# Model has no method 'isInitialized' in google drive realtime api

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I tried to add tests for the isInitialized method of a realtime model but the method appears not to be defined.

Method documentation:
https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.Model#gapi.drive.realtime.Model.prototype.isInitialized

```
model.getRoot().set('key', 'val'); // works
model.isInitialized(); // method not found error
```

Comment: @user814064 I'm using the google drive realtime api that I linked to. The Google team watches the [google-drive-realtime-api] tag; I'm mostly hoping one of them can check if there's a bug on their side.